# Woocommerce virtual type option in external product type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add the Virtual checkbox option to the External/Affiliate product type, but there is a problem with saving the _virtual value. The checkbox is always left un-checked.

```
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'add_virtual_to_external' );
function add_virtual_to_external( $product_type_options ) {
    $product_type_options['virtual']['wrapper_class'] = 'show_if_external';

    return $product_type_options;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_external', 'save_virtual_option_fields'  );
function save_virtual_option_fields( $post_id ) {
    $is_virtual = isset( $_POST['_virtual'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', $is_virtual );
}
```

Comment: What's the use case here? If it's external you aren't shipping it, so virtual seems irrelevant.